Complex triple integral needs to be transformed into something simpler and then back again
So I have
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{z_0} \int_{0}^{\rho_0} \tan^3\left[a\left(c - \frac{\sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}{b}\right)\right]d\rho\,dzd \theta$$
Which I want to integrate over the entire volume of a finite cylinder.
Now the issue is how to find the right integration limits for this in another coordinate system that allows for it to be solved analytically?

Additionally, I could break it down like this using the Trig Pythagorean identity
$$\iiint \tan\left[a\left(c - \frac{\sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}{b}\right)\right]\tan^2\left[a\left(c - \frac{\sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}{b}\right)\right]d\rho\,dzd \theta \\ = \iiint \tan\left[a\left(c - \frac{\sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}{b}\right)\right]\left(\sec^2\left[a\left(c - \frac{\sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}{b}\right)\right] - 1\right)d\rho\,dzd \theta$$
And use $r = \sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}$ but I am not sure how to transform the $d\rho\,dzd \theta$ part and the domain of integration? I think I could transform it into spherical coordinates?
I never done something this complex so forgive me if it sounds simple.
And also, I want to be able to express the final answer back into cylindrical coordinates, is it possible?

$\rho:$ Cylindrical coordinates radius
$r:$ Spherical coordinates radius, although it must have been the converse.
Conversion from cylindrical coordinates to spherical coordinates:
$$d\rho\,dz\,d\theta=\frac{\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta\,d z}{\rho}=\frac{r^2\sin\phi\,d r\,d\theta\,d\phi}{r\sin\phi}=r\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$$
$$r=\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}$$
For the change of integral bounds consider the vector $\vec{OP}$ where $O$ is the origin and $P$ is a point in the solid. That is, $OP=r.$ There is a critical angle $\phi_c$ for azimuth angle at which $\tan\phi_c=\frac{\rho_0}{z_0}.$ When $0\leq\phi\leq\phi_c$, extension of the vector $\vec{OP}$ cuts the top disk, so in this case, $0\leq r\leq\frac{z_0}{\cos\phi}$. When $\phi_c\leq\phi\leq\frac\pi2$, extension of the vector $\vec{OP}$ cuts the lateal surface, so in this case, $0\leq r\leq\frac{\rho_0}{\sin\phi}$. Therefore, we have to split the integral in two.
Hence the integral conversion is
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{z_0} \int_{0}^{\rho_0} \tan^3\left[a\left(c - \frac{\sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}{b}\right)\right]d\rho\,dzd \theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_0^{\arctan\frac{\rho_0}{z_0}} \int_{0}^{\frac{z_0}{\cos\phi}} r\,\tan^3\left(ac-\frac ab r\right)d r\,d\phi\,d \theta+
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{\arctan\frac{\rho_0}{z_0}}^{\frac\pi2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\rho_0}{\sin\phi}} r\,\tan^3\left(ac-\frac ab r\right)d r\,d\phi\,d \theta$$

Thank you for your answer. How did you obtain the integral limits? Would you be able to show the steps for that please? And also, why do we need to have 2 integrands with different limits? Further, are we able to convert the final answer after integrating back into cylindrical coordinates and would that be correct?

I did not understand your last question. Why do you wanna do that? @Mathaholic

Because the cylindrical coordinate system is the most proper one for the problem at hand, and not spherical coordinates. This is taken from a physics problem but solving this is a pure math problem for our purposes. I am just wondering if it is possible to convert it back into cylindrical coordinates after integration and would it be correct. Also, if you could answer the other questions I have written in my previous comment. Thanks
